# How to change the dropdown value based on string value in .net winforms

Tags: .net, winforms, drop-down-menu

i am using .net winform. based on my string it will focus the drop down value.

ex.

my dropdown have select value ..if i pass select as a value it should focus the select option in dropdown .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `SelectedItem` property.

```
 comboBox1.Items.Add("Apple");
 comboBox1.Items.Add("Orange");
 comboBox1.Items.Add("Banana");

 comboBox1.SelectedItem = "Orange";
```